# Problems with 100% window width/height borders on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I've been trying to fix my own site that a developer left me with and will not longer work on it.Bit by bit I'm fixing it myself. However one of the problems I'm having is with a div border that is set to frame the page (a little inset from the edges of the screen), and changes dimensions to match the current window size.

As seen here: http://dev.matthewbugeja.com/

The problem presents itself when I reduce the window size to that of a smartphone size, or small tablet size. The actual content stacks on top of each other instead of fading in and out (to be more mobile friendly). But in consequence I'm left with a large gap at the bottom of the page where the border doesn't extend to. It seems to me that it's not picking up the vertical height of the page, but I can't seem to find the code that effects this only for that size. Any advice?

Comment: The site seems perfect to me. I don't see where the issue is ._. EDIT - Oh I get it.

Comment: After 992px width or something close to that value, the section is not getting enclosed within scroll magic pin spacer. I am pretty sure that's what's causing this. If not, I apologize :p

Comment: Any ideas on how this could be fixed? I'm not as code-savvy as I used to be.